# django selenium test for form submit and redirect

Tags: django, selenium

I'm trying to do a test with selenium in django but not sure how to test that the view will put the form data in the request session and redirect correctly to the next page? 
When testing for the session value I get the following error
(possibly because I am checking for the session value on the django client and not selenium):

Error:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yunti/PycharmProjects/switcher5/switcher5/users/tests/test_functional.py", line 48, in test_postcode_signup
    self.assertEqual(postcode, self.client.session.get('postcode'))
AssertionError: 'example_postcode' != None
```

Test:

```
class MySeleniumTests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):


    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('headless')
        try:
            cls.selenium = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
        except:
            raise Exception("couldn't start headless client")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()


    def test_postcode_signup(self):
        postcode = 'example_postcode'
        self.selenium.get(f"{self.live_server_url}/users/postcode/")
        postcode_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_id('id_postcode')
        postcode_input.send_keys(postcode)
        self.selenium.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()
        #self.assertRedirect()
        #self.selenium.session? 
        self.assertEqual(postcode,self.client.session.get('postcode'))
```

Comment: What is your question here? Where are you stuck? Can you update the question with the error stack trace?

Comment: I'm stuck in that I don't know have to test for redirects with selenium or how to test session values.

Comment: Does the Chrome Browser show up?

Comment: It's running in headless mode and seems to creating the chrome webdriver ok.  I've uncommented one of the test assertions and posted a stacktrace. Thanks